# Is it possible to write only the application/pdf part of a multipart/form-data request to an AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multipartform-data, amazon-cloudfront

I have a multipart/form-data request coming into AWS S3 via AWS CloudFront containing, among others, a document field of type application/pdf.

While the non-document fields are processed in CloudFront using Lambda@Edge, the document needs to be stored in S3.

Is it possible for S3 to only write the document field in the multipart/form-data request? Currently the entire request is written, resulting is an invalid PDF document.

For example, the raw request may look something like this

```
-----80nd4ry
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field1"
Content-Type: mime/type

// value
-----80nd4ry
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="doc"; filename="doc.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.3
// content
%%EOF

-----80nd4ry
```

In its current form, the above is written as is to S3 with a .pdf extension. But what I need is to only write the following the the bucket:

```
%PDF-1.3
// content
%%EOF
```

Things tried and possible alternative solutions:

- Manipulate the body in Lambda@Edge. Problem: Body size limit of 40kB
- Read and re-write the document using an S3 trigger

I'm looking for any other ways to accomplish this, if possible.

Thanks in advance for any input.